# Black Outlines After UV Test

Tags: uv

After testing out Blender's UV functionalities all my edges have a black outline which I can't seem to get rid of.

There is no material/texture and freestyle is toggled off.

Here is a screenshot:
[image: Preview]

Thanks for your time,

neelcor

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE. The dark dots correspond to faces centers. You are in edit mode but editing faces. Press "Ctrl + tab" and choose what you want to see : vertices, edges or faces

Comment: Regardless of what selecting mode I choose, these black outlines prevail. See [here](http://i.imgur.com/DrEQUpQ.png)

Comment: is that an array ? if yes how is the original object ?

Comment: Are you just talking about the edges? If so press `Tab` to leave edit mode.